# API requests/s - Push notifications

Tags: parse-platform

i am doing the following in "didRegisterForRemoteNotification"

```
PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
[currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];
[currentInstallation saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
              NSLog(@"Device token updated! %d", succeeded);
}];
```

as this function is executed on every app launch - my question is does this count towards to the req/s count?

if so will this save my req/s count - and is this still reliable:

```
PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
if (![[currentInstallation  valueForKey:@"deviceToken"] isEqualToString:
      [[[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", deviceToken]
         stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""]
        stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""]
       stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""]]) {

          [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];
          [currentInstallation saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
              NSLog(@"Device token updated! %d", succeeded);
          }];
      } else {
          NSLog(@"DEVICE TOKEN UNCHANGED");
      }
```

i am trying to use parse.com as a push service for a large scale app (300-700k active uniq devices) - i am not using the parse-core part - so i am trying to evaluate if the 30/s free-model fits my requirements.

what happens - if the req-limit is reached - within the didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken

regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally [currentInstallation saveInBackground]  will be counted towards network api counter - it is same as saving any other object to database,  you may optimize by checking if token has changed and send only updates (I don't know if the parse SDK does this for you)

However bear in mind, that req/s is enforced by the minute, not every second, so it is not 30reqs / second but rather 1800 reqs / minute which give much wider margin for number of users :-)
When limit is reached, requests overflowing it are dropped. You may retry the request for example... I think that either saveInBackground or saveEventually do retries .